# Blender rigging join two ik-chain in one system

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms

I can't solve this problem in any way (marked "trouble" on gif)

"A" and "C" are separate IK-chains that work well. But, I cannot connect them correctly.

"C.2" bone locked rotation, only location transform. In this example was try to use Limit distance constraint from "B.1" bone to "A.IK-target" bone. And "C.IK-target" bone use Locked track constraint to "B.1" bone.

[image]

[image]

Update:

This is rig of door. All joints must be connected and must not separate in animation.

[image]

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com Also, give us a clear idea of how you want the desired results to be different from the ones you've already shown.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with 3 ik-chains, finished file attached

https://blend-exchange.com/b/8MybezWq

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the fact that the original bone ***B.1*** is always at a **constant angle**, it can be aggregated into a single IK system.
[image]

[image]